# Create iOS app without menu icon

Tags: ios

I'm creating a keyboard application in iOS. The usage of this application will be very specific:
1. From the text messaging application
2. From the browser, when I hit 'Share'

So, the app itself won't do anything from the menu. My question is, do we absolutely have to need to have an icon in the menu, or can I not have one? I had an icon and only displayed the company logo, but when I submitted it to Apple, they responded saying it doesn't give good user experience and rejected it.

I have seen similar questions, but these were from way back in 2012-14. I am wondering if something has changed (I'm a novice dev, this is literally my first time doing iOS).

Comment: The situation did not change, your app should have an icon and will display on the Home screen.

Comment: An app needs to be useful by itself. Apple won't accept what you are referring to.

Comment: I was going through some keyboard extension apps. I found Link Prettiifier (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/link-prettifier-create-beautiful-custom-links/id1154063589?mt=8) which when installed doesnt have an icon in the menu/launch screen. It can be used only from the keyboard. 
I'm wondering then how does this app do it