# App rejected by Apple based on design guideline

Tags: ios, imessage-extension

Apple rejected our app with the following response:

We noticed an issue in your app that contributes to a lower quality user experience than Apple users expect:
- Upon launching the app, a web page in mobile Safari opens first, then returns to the app. The user should be able to use the app immediately upon launch.
Next Steps
To resolve this issue, please revise your app to address all instances of this type of issue.

---

The app we're developing is a keyboard extension. The use-cases do not require a user to actually open the app and use it. As a result, in the app itself (should you launch it from home/springboard), we redirect the user to our website, which informs the user how to use the product (there's no registration or immediate tutorial required, but we certainly cant have the app do absolutely nothing). From Apple's response, this clearly isn't the right way. My questions:

1. If a user were to be redirected to Messages, could this solve the problem?  The reason I ask this instead of just trying it is so that I dont waste time and end up getting rejected again.
2. Part of the problem seems that opening the app through springboard is misleading since it doesnt do anything. But my understanding is that we cannot have apps without icons ([Create iOS app without menu icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249772/create-ios-app-without-menu-icon)). Do keyboard apps need to be published differently so that we dont have an icon in springboard? If so, please direct me to some documentation/Xcode configuration/resources to achieve this.

This is my first attempt at mobile development

Comment: You could give your app a simple `WKWebView` UI that loads the same page as your redirect, so as to keep the user in the app but still display the information you consider relevant. At least you'd address the specific concern about opening mobile Safari on launch.

Comment: That seems to be the most obvious solution. But I wanted to get some direction before I spent more time in coding. I'll give it a shot

Comment: Have the app present a button (How to use, Tips) that loads the web page when pressed.  That would avoid the automatic loading of a web page.

Comment: @vacawama the question is, would even just doing that suffice.

Comment: It's what Swype did. I'd check a few free keyboards in the store and see what they did.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @particleman was the right one. Just loading a `WebView` within the app was enough for Apple to accept the app.